# How can I create derived class object from an existing base class object?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to create a derived class object and populate the data-members (coming from base class) with a existing base class object.

In my process lifecycle, I already had a base class object. For some decision, I have to create a new object (derived from base class). One way to do this is expose the assessors and copy the data. Is there any solution like aggregate initialization or dynamic_cast that I could use instead?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Base {
    protected: 
        string name_;

    public:
        Base() : name_ ("foo")
        {
        }
        void ChangeName()
        {
            name_ = std::string {"bar"};
        }
};

class Child final : Base {
    public:
    string GetName()
    {
        return name_;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base b;
    b.ChangeName();

    Child c = {b};
    cout<<"Hello World. Here is my name: " << c.GetName() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

> Expected Output:
>   Hello World. Here is my name: bar

Compilation Error

```
try.cpp:33:17: error: could not convert ‘{b}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘Child’
     Child c = {b};
```

Comment: What problem are you having?  Compilation errors?  Incorrect output?  [Edit] your question to add the details.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Added Compilation error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to construct a `Child` from a `Base`, you need to add a constructor to `Child` that will do that:

```
Child(const Base &b): Base(b) { }
```

You need to be cautious using this, as it will allow constructing a `Child` from another class that is also derived from `Base`.  And if `Child` has any other data members, you need to be sure to add appropriate initialization or default values for them.

Comment: That is a better solution, Thanks! Quick question: When I try a different derivative of Base, I get the following error:

error: ‘Base’ is an inaccessible base of ‘Child2’

Comment: @VarunPandey That's because `Base` is a private base of `Child1` (and I assume for `Child2` as well.  This will avoid the problem I've mentioned, but if you have a public base class (`class Child3: public Base') the construction would happen.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this is possible using the C-style casts:

```
Child c(*(Child*)&b);
```

But I wouldn't advise you to use this. It can fail if the memory layouts of the classes aren't similar. The equivalent C++ cast for this situation is this:

```
Child c(*reinterpret_cast<Child*>(&b));
```

**EDIT:** Turns out this is Undefined Behavior. Don't attempt this :)

Comment: That's UB, plain and simple. Even when you think the layouts match, the complexities of compiling your description of a program into something a computer can understand render this approach completely unreliable. _Avoid UB._ I cannot stress this enough.

Comment: Is it the conversion that's UB or the member access?

Comment: All of it! You are telling the computer that an A is a B when it is not.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. I've updated my answer.